# Cannot fully uninstall google drive on mac

Tags: macos, google-apps

Google drive is terrible software for backing up your files.  I'm now trying to get rid of it but am having a hard time getting back all the gigs that it devoured.  I read the recomendations for doing so here:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250055023

I was backing up 20 gigs worth of dating on my mac with google drive.  I moved those files to external hard drive, deleted google drive but till now I have not got back any of the gigs that it devoured.  In fact, I have not freed up any space on my laptop since I deleted google drive.  I cannot access any of the docs that was contained in those 20 gigs but I have just as much free space on my laptop as before.

I should also add that there are a lot of companies out there claiming to clean up your mac.  I'm not using any of them since I believe them to be malware.

Comment: Do your backups contain the files you wish to clean up?

Comment: if you mean when i log onto drive.google.com and the files are there which i recently deleted from my laptop, then yes.  i'm going to move them onto two hard drives then delete them from drive.google.com - we'll see if that works

Comment: ok, finished deleting files from drive.google.com - that didn't change things.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with this command:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/DriveFS/[0-9]*
```